# How to delete laravel built-in two migration files?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2. I want to delete two laravel built-in migration files `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` and `2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php`. But PhpStorm told me that there are two usages in other files' code. So if I delete them, I first delete two files' usages, and then delete two files, is that right?

Comment: Just un-check 'Safe Delete'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, check in your `migrations` table if the file is migrated. If its migrated you can use: `php artisan migrate:rollback`.

You can delete the files, after that you can run: `composer dump-autoload`, this will recreate all the files generated by composer.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

If you've already ran `migrate` command, run `php artisan rollback`. Then delete these two files and run `composer dumpauto`